# Trying to understand the error in my code

Tags: c

I'm creating a code where someone enters the amount of people eating a cut from  and from there I can figure out how many pieces I can have in one pizza.I'm having trouble and don't know how to fix my error.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int Cuts(int n)
{
    int max = n*2;
    
return m;
}

int main()
{
    int m;
    m = Cuts();
    printf("P1:%d\n" , m);
}
```

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Why do you multiply the number by 2?

Comment: Where do you enter the number of people?

Comment: If the maximum number of people is the same as the number of slices, I'm not sure why you are trying to return the same value in two different sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CutYourPizza function is written to require one integer argument (called n), but when you invoked that function on the line `max = CutYourPizza();` you did not supply any argument.

For example, if you wanted to supply the number 10 as an argument, then you could have written `max = CutYourPizza(10);` with the argument 10 inside the parentheses.

Comment: No, a variable is just fine.

Comment: So if you had a variables (perhaps called `people`), you could pass it to the function as an argument instead of passing a constant number (like 10).

Comment: You could certainly use scanf first to have the user input a number into the variable before you passed it over to your function.